# AWS Lambda + Python - No module named pkg_resources

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I am trying to create a python deployment package for AWS Lambda. I have followed documentation specified at Creating a [Deployment Package (Python)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html)

While testing created Lambda function, I am getting following error:

```
No module named pkg_resources
```

On debugging, identified that `pint` package requires this `pkg_resources`. AFAIK, `pkg_resources` will be created during Python distro installation.

I am assuming since Python is already available on Lambda server, it should also have the `pkg_resources`.

What am I missing here? Can someone please help?

Before downvoting: If this is a wrong forum for this question, please comment on the question and I will move to correct Forum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A good way to make sure that all the packages are available to you is installing all the dependencies in the `AWS AMI`. It offers the same environment as lambda at bootstrap. This way you will be able to find out which packages are missing from the `AWS AMI` python and python installed on your system. You might want to look at frameworks like [serverless](https://serverless.com/) which have plugins like [serverless-python-requirements](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-python-requirements) which can build packages for you. I usually create a [`venv`](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/) and check everything is working. Here is [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) which shows you how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

I found this useful [link](https://gist.github.com/gene1wood/4a052f39490fae00e0c3) which lists out all python modules installed in lambda execution environment. Though this link list out for Python 2.7, you can refer this for Python 3.6 as well. If a module you need is not present in this list, you can package it with the ZIP file.

AWS doc also mentions [list of available libraries](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/current-supported-versions.html) for lambda execution env, but it just mentions `Boto3` package and doesn't explicitly list out the modules/dependent modules along with it.